# Various included packages suddenly “Failed to parse the manifest file”

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

In my team we had a problem with our included SPM packages. Everything worked fine the other day, and then trying to build the project or to reset spm cache always fails with almost all packages saying `Failed to parse the manifest file`.

Even creating a new user and using a clean clone doesn't help, as soon as the error appeared once there seems to be no fixing. Today, another team member came suddenly up with the same problem. We will be trying to further investigate, but please, if anyone has had a similar problem/any advice, we would greatly appreciate it.

Xcode 13.1, macOS 11.6 and 12.0.1

See attached screenshot for the error.

[image: spm error]

Comment: If you use Git (or SVN), can you go back to a previous version where it worked? Maybe a diff somewhere?

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks like its related to antivirus software ... wow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, after trying different things it looks like antivirus/TrendMicro Security Agent had to do something with the problems. After uninstalling it, Xcode/SPM returned to work like a charm.